# Convert the to-be-sorted list into an array of sub arrays with each item before doing Merge Sort

Tags: javascript, algorithm, sorting, mergesort

Maybe I have misunderstanding on Merge sort. Can someone explain to me if I break the `toBeSorted` list into array of sub arrays like this:

```
const toBeSorted = [2,4,5,1,6,8]
const brokenDown = [[2],[4],[5],[1],[6],[8]]
```

then I do the usual sort and merge thing with the subarrays inside `brokenDown`. What is the difference or drawbacks comparing to the classic original solution?

I understand merge sort as halving the original list down till each sub array only contain one item, then sort them and merge them together. So instead of halving, I just iterate through the original array and make it an array of subarrays.

I tried both solutions, the classic one took around 3000ms to sort 200,000 while my solution took 5000ms to sort the same amount of data.

So I think I am lacking some understanding on Merge Sort.

my solution full code:

```js
(() => {
let i = 0
const data = []
const size = 200000
while (i < size) {
 data.push(Math.round(Math.random() * 1000))
 i++
}

function mergeSort(arr) {
  
  if (arr.length < 2) return arr[0]

  const output = []
  for (let i=0; i<arr.length; i+=2) {
    output.push(sortAndStitch(arr[i], arr[i+1]))
  }

  return mergeSort(output)
}

function breakDown(arr) {
  const output = []
  for (item of data) {
    output.push([item])
  }
  return output
}

function sortAndStitch(sub1, sub2) {
  const arr1 = sub1 || [], arr2 = sub2 || [], output = []
  
  while(arr1.length && arr2.length) {

    if (arr1[0] > arr2[0]) {
      output.push(arr2.shift())
    } else {
      output.push(arr1.shift())
    }
  }

  return output.concat(...arr1, ...arr2)
  
}

const start = new Date().getTime()

mergeSort(breakDown(data))

const interval = new Date().getTime() - start + 'ms'

console.log({ size, interval })

})()
```

the classic solution that I am comparing to:

```js
(() => {
let i = 0
const data = []
const size = 200000
while (i < size) {
 data.push(Math.round(Math.random() * 1000))
 i++
}

const mergeSort = nums => {
  if (nums.length < 2) {
    return nums;
  }
  const length = nums.length;
  const middle = Math.floor(length / 2);
  const left = nums.slice(0, middle);
  const right = nums.slice(middle);
  
  return merge(mergeSort(left), mergeSort(right));
};

const merge = (left, right) => {
  
  const results = [];
  
  while (left.length && right.length) {
    
    if (left[0] <= right[0]) {
      results.push(left.shift());
    }
    else {
      results.push(right.shift());
    }
  }
  
  return results.concat(left, right);
};

const start = new Date().getTime()

mergeSort(data)

const interval = new Date().getTime() - start + 'ms'

console.log({ size, interval })

})()
```

Comment: Both approaches are valid, see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Merge_sort#Algorithm, "top down" vs "bottom up". As to why the bottom-up is slower, you can profile it more precisely, e.g. using `console.time`. I'm suspecting the spread `concat(...arr1, ...arr2)` is to blame.

Comment: Also, make sure you test with the *same* data. Right now, each is generating each own set. Right here, I sometimes get very close results, other times something more significant, say, 20% difference.

Comment: @georg - the wiki examples use one temporary array and use indexing to keep track of sub-array boundaries, rather than creating sub-arrays and pop/push numbers to those sub-arrays. I have an indexed based bottom up merge sort that sorts 200,000 numbers in less than 50 ms, versus the first example which takes ~14500 ms and the second example which takes ~3500 ms on my system (Intel 3770K 3.5 ghz, Windows 7 Pro 64 bit, Chrome).

Comment: @georg - removing the spread made a big difference, but it's still slow on my system.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first example pushes n = 200,000 sub-arrays of size 1 to create an array of n = 200,000 sub-arrays. Then for each "pass", it indexes two sub-arrays from the array of sub-arrays, merges them into a single sub-array, and pushes that sub-array onto yet another array of sub-arrays. So the code ends up creating 19 arrays of sub-arrays (including the original), by pushing the sub-arrays onto arrays of sub-arrays, which ends up as 400000+ pushes of sub-arrays onto arrays of sub-arrays. Those arrays of sub-arrays are also consuming a lot of space.

The second example splits the array into two sub-arrays, then recursion follows only the left sub-arrays until a sub-array of size 1 is reached, then a right sub-array of size 1 is reached, and only then does merging begin, following the call chain up and down, depth first, left first. Only 18 levels of recursion occur, and the shifts and pushes are only performed on arrays of numbers, while the first example is also performing those 400000+ pushes of sub-arrays onto arrays of sub-arrays.

An indexed based merge sort (top down or bottom up) would be much faster for either first or second example, taking about 50 ms to sort 200,000 numbers. As commented above, Wikipedia has psuedo code examples:

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Merge_sort

> classic original solution

The "classic original solution" is bottom up merge sort. The 1945 EDVAC that Von Newmann described a merge sort for didn't have a stack. Prior to that, Hollerith card sorters, dating back to 1887, used radix sort. The IBM type 77 collators (1937) could merge two decks of sorted cards into a single merged deck, which is what probably gave Von Newmann the idea of merge sort in 1945, followed up in 1948 with a description and analysis of bottom up merge sort.

The first practical non-punched card based sorts were tape sorts (variations of bottom up merge sort), used on the Univac 1 (early 1950's) which could have up to 10 Uniservo tape drives.

Most libraries use some variation of hybrid insertion (on small sub-arrays) + bottom up merge sort for stable sort. Run time for insertion + top down merge sort is about the same, but recursion could throw a stack overflow exception mid-sort. Example hybrid insertion + bottom up merge sort (on my system (Intel 3770K 3.5 ghz, Windows 7 Pro 64 bit, to sort 200,000 numbers, Chrome takes ~40 ms, IE 11 takes ~35 ms.

```js
function merge(a, b, bgn, mid, end) {
  var i = bgn                           // left:  a[bgn,mid)
  var j = mid                           // right: a[mid,end)
  var k = bgn                           // index for b[]
  while(true){
    if(a[i] <= a[j]){                   // if left <= right
      b[k++] = a[i++]                   //   copy left
      if(i < mid)                       //   if not end of left
        continue                        //     continue back to while
      do                                //   else copy rest of right
        b[k++] = a[j++]
      while(j < end)
      break                             //     and break
    } else {                            // else left > right
      b[k++] = a[j++]                   //   copy right
      if(j < end)                       //   if not end of right
        continue                        //     continue back to while
      do                                //   else copy rest of left
        b[k++] = a[i++]
      while(i < mid)
      break                             //     and break
    }
  }
}

function insertionsort(a, ll, rr)
{
  var i = ll+1
  while(i < rr){
    var t = a[i]
    var j = i
    while((j > ll) && a[j-1] > t){
      a[j] = a[j-1]
      j -= 1}
    a[j] = t
    i += 1}
}

function getpasscount(n)                // return # passes
{
  var i = 0
  for(var s = 1; s < n; s <<= 1)
    i += 1
  return(i)
}

function mergesort(a)
{
  var n = a.length
  if(n < 2)                             // if size < 2 return
    return
  var b = new Array(n)                  // allocate temp array
  var s = 64                            // set run size
  if(0 != (1&getpasscount(n)))          //  for even # of passes
    s = 32
  for(var rr = 0; rr < n; ){            // do insertion sorts
    var ll = rr;
    rr += s;
    if(rr > n)
      rr = n;
    insertionsort(a, ll, rr);
  }
  while(s < n){                         // while not done
    var ee = 0                          // reset end index
    while(ee < n){                      // merge pairs of runs
      var ll = ee                       // ll = start of left  run
      var rr = ll+s                     // rr = start of right run
      if(rr >= n){                      // if only left run
        do                              //   copy it
          b[ll] = a[ll]
        while(++ll < n)
        break                           //   end of pass
      }
      ee = rr+s                         // ee = end of right run
      if(ee > n)
        ee = n
      merge(a, b, ll, rr, ee)           // merge a[left],a[right] to b[]
    }
    var t = a                           // swap array references
    a = b
    b = t
    s <<= 1                             // double the run size
  }
}

var a = new Array(200000)
for (var i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
  a[i] = Math.round(Math.random() * 1000000000)
}
console.time('measure')
mergesort(a)
console.timeEnd('measure')
for (var i = 1; i < a.length; i++) {
  if(a[i-1] > a[i]){
    console.log('error')
    break
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for answering the question so thoroughly. I learnt a lot from it. sorry for taking so long to accept the answer.